# please could anyone provide me a clear idea over piece of code to get executed

Tags: apex

Below I there are fields of two lists which I am trying to compare and provide a flag accordingly. Here the attempt is to compare and insert the new feed records so that we don't get a duplicate record for Bank Statement : code is as below

```
List<Bank_Statements__c> bd;
if(BF!=null){
   system.debug(BF.Id);
   system.debug('Inside if ');
   bd = [Select id, Name, Bank_Account_Number__c, Bank_Name__c, Amount__c, Current_Balance__c, categoryName__c, chqNo__c, Date__c, Tx_Type__c from Bank_Statements__c where Bank_Facilities__c =: BF.id];
   system.debug('!!!!!bd!!!!'+bd);
}   
if(bd.size()>0 && bd!=null){
    bankstatement = i;
    bd = j;
    String FoundInOLD = 'N';
    String NotFound   = 'Y';
    for(i = 0; i<=bankstatement.size(); i++){       
        for(j = 0; j<=bd.size(); j++) {
          if(bankstatement[i].Date__c = bd[j].Date__c && bankstatement[i].chqNo__c = bd[j].chqNo__c && bankstatement[i].Amount__c = bd[j].Amount__c && bankstatement[i].categoryName__c = bd[j].categoryName__c && bankstatement[i].Current_Balance__c = bd[j].Current_Balance__c && bankstatement[i].Tx_Type__c = bd[j].Tx_Type__c){
                flag =='N';
          } 
        }                               
    }
    flag =='Y';
    Insert Bankstatement;
}
```

Any Help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole lot of weirdness going on here and some missing context. Using strings as flags is odd, `if(bd.size()>0 && bd!=null){` will blow up if `bd` is `null`, this:

```
bankstatement = i;
```

conflicts with:

```
for(i = 0; i<=bankstatement.size(); i++){
```

How can `i` be an integer and a list at the same time? The same goes for `j`. There's so many issues here it's impossible to go through it all without getting more information and more code, but that doesn't mean I can't try and offer some advice.

In short, you could just query using a `WHERE` clause that checks all the fields in question. If there's a result, then don't insert the new one. But given these are bank transactions I'd be hugely surprised if they didn't have a unique identifier other than the Salesforce record Id, in which case querying against that should be enough. If you setup such a field as a unique external ID in Salesforce you wouldn't even need any code to protect against duplicates.